# Move other items down when opening ExpanderView

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

I have four toolkit:ExpanderView items on a page. What I want is for the ExpanderViews below the targeted one to move down, leaving space for the one that I need to open. What can I do to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I remember, each exapnder has an "IsExpanded" Property. Just set it to "True" to show or to "False" to collapse and give other stuff more space. 
Possible by Databinding and as codebehind.

```
private void SetExpanded(bool expand)
{
    foreach (object item in this.listBox.Items)
    {
        CustomPizza customPizza = item as CustomPizza;
        if (customPizza != null)
        {
            customPizza.IsExpanded = expand;
        }
    }
}
```